# MySQL Left join 1 result for very big DataBase

Tags: mysql, database, left-join, movies

I have a big database of movies and I want to search movies by years and genres.

I have 3 table to deal with:

```
1. movies (Key TITLE_ID)
2. movie2genre (TITLE_ID + GENRE_ID)
3. genre (Key GENRE_ID)
```

**movies:**

```
+----------+---------------+------+
| TITLE_ID |     TITLE     | YEAR |
+----------+---------------+------+
|  10001   | Matrix        | 1999 |
|  10002   | Walk on Water | 2004 |
+----------+---------------+------+
```

**movie2genre:**

```
+----------+----------+
| TITLE_ID | GENRE_ID |
+----------+----------+
|  10001   |    1     |
|  10001   |    2     |
|  10002   |    2     |
|  10002   |    4     |
|  10001   |    3     |
+----------+----------+
```

**genre:**

```
+----------+-----------+
| GENRE_ID | GENRE_TXT |
+----------+-----------+
|    1     | Action    |
|    2     | Adventure |
|    3     | Thriller  |
|    4     | Fantasy   |
+----------+-----------+
```

A user sends a request for year 1999, genre Adventure or Thriller.

How can I find all movies in 1 optimized query?

**Result should be:**

```
+----------+--------+------+-----------+
| TITLE_ID | TITLE  | YEAR | GENRE_TXT |
+----------+--------+------+-----------+
|  10001   | Matrix | 1999 |  Action   |
+----------+--------+------+-----------+
```

I don't care which genre gets selected, only that this movie as 1 of genres user ask for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try joining together the 3 tables and then restricting the query with a `WHERE` clause using your requirements for year and movie genre.  The query below will return only one record, which you specified would be acceptable.

```
SELECT m.TITLE_ID, m.TITLE, m.YEAR, g.GENRE_TXT
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN movie2genre mg ON m.TITLE_ID = mg.TITLE_ID
INNER JOIN genre g ON mg.GENRE_ID = g.GENRE_ID
WHERE m.YEAR = 1999 AND g.GENRE_TXT IN ('Adventure', 'Thriller')
```

Comment: I would remove the LIMIT... the OP wants all movies... just his sample data would return only 1 from what is displayed. (but upvoted for accurate query otherwise)

Comment: Thank you! Working great. I just add "GROUP BY m.TITLE_ID" to get 1 result for movie.

Comment: @TheWiz, take a look at Help -> Tour for site etiquette and marking answers as resolved (checkmark next to answer).  Lets others know what worked and others don't have to keep offering solutions when no longer needed :)